# Selenium-IDE href value without clicking

Tags: selenium, monitoring, selenium-ide

I am quite new to the Selenium. I tried to search for similar questions/issues, but did not find.
I need to create Test Case in Selenium IDE. Test case goes to a web page https://demo.centreon.com. It logs nicely in. But then I want the Selenium to check that the Down hosts count is for example 0.

The code when checking the elements is:

[image: [2]]
How should I configure it to Selenium IDE to show me error when the count is something else than 0?

Answer (score 0):

In selenium you're going to want to utilize an assert. For your example it might be best select the URL and to assert the final URL e.g. main.php?p=20202&o=down&search=0 or whatever your case might be. More on that here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#assertion-or-verification

The downside is that using Selenium IDE can be limiting and eventually you're going to want to use a language binding e.g. python, java, ruby, etc. try using Selenium IDE to export the test in a language and experiment.